# Using perl's reduce to compute dot-product

Tags: perl, dot-product

Suppose I have the following two equal-sized arrays in my `perl` program:

```
my @arr1 = 1..5;
my @arr2 = 6..10;
```

I'm trying to get their dot-product using the `reduce` function defined in the `List::Util` core module but the following is not working for me:

```
my $dot_prod = reduce { $arr1[$a] * $arr2[$a] + $arr1[$b] * $arr2[$b] }0..$#arr1;
```

I get **50** as my output instead of the expected **130**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) describes the behavior of `reduce` as follows:

> The first call will be with $a and $b set to the first two elements of
>   the list, subsequent calls will be done by setting $a to the result of
>   the previous call and $b to the next element in the list.

Thus, in this case, on the first iteration `reduce` will set `$a = 0` and `$b = 1`, and hence, execute

```
$arr1[0] * $arr2[0] + $arr1[1] * $arr2[1]
```

This temporary result happens to be **20**.

Now, for the second iteration, `$a` is set to the result of the previous iteratrion and so `$a = 20` and `$b = 2`. Thus, the following will be executed

```
$arr1[20] * $arr2[20] + $arr1[2] * $arr2[2]
```

which is **not** what we want.

**A possible workaround:**

prepend an initial `0` to the list provided as input to `reduce` as follows:

```
my $dot_prod = reduce { $a + $arr1[$b] * $arr2[$b] } 0, 0..$#arr1;
```

This gives us the desired result since on the first iteration `$a = $b = 0` and  we'll compute

```
0 + $arr[0] * $arr[0]
```

whose result will be **6**.

Then in the second iteration, we'll have `$a = 6` `$b = 1` and so we'll compute

```
6 + $arr1[1] * $arr2[1]
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly,

```
my $dot_prod = reduce { $a + $arr1[$b] * $arr2[$b] } 0, 0..$#arr1;
```

isn't the most readable. There is this:

```
my $dot_prod = sum map { $arr1[$_]*$arr2[$_] } 0..$#arr1;
```

But that doesn't use `reduce`. Well, we could simply implement `sum` in terms of `reduce` instead of using List::Util's, and perhaps even inline it:

```
my $dot_prod = reduce { $a+$b } map { $arr1[$_]*$arr2[$_] } 0..$#arr1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the previously posted solutions in a runnable program:

```
my @arr1 = 1..3;
my @arr2 = 6..8;

use List::Util qw(reduce sum) ;

my $dot_prod0 = reduce { $a + $arr1[$b] * $arr2[$b] } 0,0..$#arr1;       #reduce

print "Dot product0 = ".$dot_prod0."\n";
my $dot_prod1 = sum map  { $arr1[$_]*$arr2[$_] } 0..$#arr1;              #sum map
print "Dot product1 = ".$dot_prod1."\n";
my $dot_prod2 = reduce { $a+$b } map { $arr1[$_]*$arr2[$_] } 0..$#arr1;  #reduce map
print "Dot product2 = ".$dot_prod2."\n";
```

Comment: That's byte for byte three solutions I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349251/589924) seven years earlier in response to the same question. Not even an attribution. That's rude, and a violation of the terms of the site. I have added an introduction that serves as attribution.